# Jquery, ajax and php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have this code to present images:

```
<?php foreach ($images as $row) : ?>      
                    <div class="box col_3">
                        <p><a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>public/images/fullscreen/<?php echo $row['image'] ?>" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="<?php echo $row['title'] ?>">
                                <img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>public/images/thumbnails/<?php echo $row['image_thumb'] ?>" title="<?php echo $row['title'] ?>" ></a></p>                            

                                <textarea name="title_image" rows="3" class="title_image"><?php echo $row['title'] ?></textarea>
                                        <input type="hidden" class="id_image" class="id_image"  value="<?php echo $row['id_image'] ?>" >
                                        <input type="submit" name="update_image" id="update_image" value="Update" class="submit" /><br>
                        <a href="#" class="delete" id="<?php echo $row['id_image'] ?>">Delete image</a>
                    </div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
```

User can upload an image, and for every image div with class of box is created.
This is the code which sends data for update.

```
$(function(){        
    $('.submit').click(function(){
       ('.box').append('<img src="<?php echo IMG ?>loadinfo.net.gif" id="loading" />');
        var id = $('.id_image').val();            
        var title = $('.title_image').val();         

        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo site_url('gallery/update_image') ?>",
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'id=' + id + '&title=' + title,
            success: function(){
                $('#loading').fadeOut(500, function(){
                    $(this).remove();
                });
            }
        });          
         return false;
    });                 
});
```

This works just for the first box, and for the rest it doesn't. What I need to do to make it work?

Comment: Why doesnt it work? What error messages do you see, what is supposed to happen and what happens instead?

Comment: @TJHeuvel: He says it in the last line of his question....

Comment: Function update description of the image. When I try to update image other the one in the first box I get:
Message: Undefined index: title, Undefined index: id

Comment: @Baszz not entirely. Sure he says it works for the first, and not for the second, but its not clear exactly what doesnt work for the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are referencing css classes within your javascript

```
$('.id_image').val()
```

this will always return the value of the first appearance of this class e.g. the first image.
try to traverse through the DOM using your submit button as start
e.g.

```
$('.submit').click(function(){
var id = $(this).prevAll('.id_image').val();
```

this should return the correct value for id.
then you can use the same method to get the title

to update the loading image use the same method, but this time you'll have to use the parents() selector

```
$(this).parents('.box').append('<img src="<?php echo IMG ?>loadinfo.net.gif" id="loading" />');
```

as you are now assigning only a single loading image the removal function should work as expected

Comment: It is working :D. One more question. When update is clicked, it load loading gif, but it loads on all boxes, and after successes it is removed only on first. How to limit loading just the box where update is clicked?